# Create a days of month using a date as parameter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office

I have a date in cell `A1` for example: 12/08/22

I want create a list with all days of the month (1-31) in column `E` using the `month` and `year` of the cell `A1` as parameter.

```
Sub TESTEEEEEEE()

    Dim r As Range, i As String, j As Long
     i = Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
    'k = ????
    j = 31
    For Each r In Range("E1:E31")
        r.NumberFormat = "@"
        r.Value = Format(DateSerial(k, i, j), "dd/m/yy")
         j = j + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

I'm stucked in how to extract the the month and year. I was trying using the position of the characteres as parameter, but i'm not getting it work.

`i` should extract the 4,5 and characterer returning `08` (ok, the code is wrong i was making some tests).

`k` should extract the 7,8 charachter returning `22`.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Use the [Month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) and [Year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function) function. Further [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-monthly-calendar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try using the next way. It does not need iteration:

```
Sub testCreateWholeMonth()
   Dim D As Date, lastD As Long
   D = Range("A1").value
   
   lastD = Day(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(DateSerial(Year(D), Month(D), 1), 0))
   With Range("E1:E" & lastD)
        .value = Evaluate("date(" & Year(D) & "," & Month(D) & ",row(1:" & lastD & "))")
        .NumberFormat = "mm.dd.yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably after calendar functions like [YEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function), [MONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function), [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.eomonth)

```
Sub DebugDate()

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1")  ' should contain a date
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = rg.Value

    Debug.Print Year(dt), Month(dt), CDate(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dt, 0))
    ' End of month not using worksheet function EOMONTH
    Debug.Print DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt) + 1, 1) - 1

End Sub
```

Further reading on [How to create a calendar with VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-monthly-calendar)